# Can you optimize a matrix function instead of a vector?

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, matrix-multiplication

I have the following matrices for weights and stock returns for two assets A and B:

```
weights = np.array([[.6, .4], [.5, .5], [.4, .6]]) # all elements w: 0 < w < 1
returns = np.array([[1.25, 2.5], [0.64, 0.5], [1.5, 1.6]]).T
```

I want to find a new matrix of weights that optimizes the product of the diagonal of the product of the two matrices like this:

```
def objective_function(weights, returns):

    mat = np.product(np.diag(weights @ returns)) - 1
    return mat

>>> 0.5561
```

I am struggling to find an optimization package or algorithm that works as they all only seem to generate a 1d vector that optimizes the function.

I tried flattening the weight matrix and reshaping it in the function as a work around like so:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize

# Reshape function to take 3x2 matrix
def funct(weights_flat):
    weights = weights_flat.reshape((3, 2))
    mat = -(np.product(np.diag(weights @ returns)) - 1)
    return mat

# Constraints: sum of each column should be 1
constraints = ({'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda w: np.sum(w, axis=0) - 1})

# Initial guess (1D array)
initial_guess_flat = np.ones(6)

# Perform the optimization using scipy.optimize
result = minimize(funct, initial_guess_flat, method='SLSQP', constraints=constraints)

# Get the optimized weights
optimized_weights = result.x.reshape((3, 2))

print("Optimized Weights:")
print(optimized_weights)
```

the above just results in a matrix of NaN values.

```
>>> Optimized Weights:
[[nan nan]
 [nan nan]
 [nan nan]]
```

Could anyone advise how to reconfigure the optimization function to work as intended or suggest an alternative package/algorithm suitable for my problem?

Comment: Flattening&reshaping is a way to go. What I do not understand is why you return matrix in objective_function. Instead you should provide single value - loss/error/whatever.

Comment: the function returns a scalar rather than a matrix. I need to update the name.

Comment: ah right, did not read thoroughly. Yes, cleaning code before asking question helps :)

Comment: [AI-generative content is banned on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned).

Answer (score 0):

1. Constraint function does not seem to achieve objective "sum of each column should be 1", as you sum over entire flattened vector, you should reshape before summing.
2. Even when it is corrected, where is nothing that limits `weights` matrix' entries from growing to +/- infinities, which cancel out and give columns with sum 1, while decreasing funct to minus infinity (as you minimize this function's value, not it's magnitude!). My guess is what you actually wanted is criterion `mat = np.abs(np.product(np.diag(weights @ returns)) - 1)` in cost function, or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

A long list of misses, but this should fix it up. Long story short, yes, you need to reshape; and also don't rely on hard-coded matrix dimensions.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import LinearConstraint, minimize, Bounds


def objective_function(weights_flat: np.ndarray, returns: np.ndarray) -> float:
    weights = weights_flat.reshape(returns.shape[::-1])
    # Diagonal of matrix product
    mul = np.einsum('ij,ji->i', weights, returns)
    return mul.prod() - 1


def main() -> None:
    returns = np.array((
        (1.25, 0.64, 1.5),
        (2.50, 0.50, 1.6),
    ))

    # sum of each column should be 1 (OP changed their mind to rows)
    # constraint = LinearConstraint(
    #     A=np.tile(
    #         A=np.eye(returns.shape[0]),
    #         reps=returns.shape[1],
    #     ),
    #     lb=1, ub=1,
    # )

    # sum of each row should be 1
    constraint = LinearConstraint(
        A=np.repeat(
            a=np.eye(returns.shape[1]),
            repeats=returns.shape[0], axis=1,
        ),
        lb=1, ub=1,
    )

    x0 = np.full(
        shape=np.prod(returns.shape),
        fill_value=1/returns.shape[0],
    )

    result = minimize(
        fun=objective_function,
        x0=x0,
        bounds=Bounds(lb=-1, ub=1),
        constraints=constraint,
        args=(returns,),
    )
    if not result.success:
        raise ValueError(result.message)

    weights = result.x.reshape(returns.shape[::-1])
    print(f'Objective: {result.fun:.3f}')
    print('Row sums:', weights.sum(axis=1))
    print('Optimized weights:')
    print(weights)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

```
Objective: -0.063
Row sums: [1. 1. 1.]
Optimized weights:
[[ 1.00000000e+00 -5.03098815e-16]
 [ 1.95222699e-16  1.00000000e+00]
 [ 1.00000000e+00  1.94289029e-16]]
```

Comment: Thanks, i'll use rets.shape for the reshape of the weights. Above works well although I want the rows to sum to 1 rather than the columns.

Comment: @python_beginner That's not what your comments said; but oh well - I fixed it up